# How to replace entire string occurrences, not substrings, in a Polars DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, replace, python-polars

I am working with a Polars DataFrame that contains thousands of string columns, and I am looking for a way to replace all instances of the string "0" with "-1" in the entire DataFrame.

Here is the code I have attempted:

```
df.with_columns(pl.all().str.replace("0", "-1", literal=True))
```

However, I encountered an issue with this approach. When a cell contains a string like "011212", the result becomes "-111212", which is not the desired outcome. My intention is to exclusively replace the entire string "0" with "-1" while leaving any strings containing the substring "0" unchanged.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you saying only if the string is exactly "0" that you want to switch it to "-1" and leave everything else alone?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Yes, exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Expr.replace()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html#polars.Expr.replace) is for replacing "values" as opposed to "substrings".

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": [1, 2, 3],
   "B": ["0", "00", "10"],
})

df.with_columns(
   pl.col(pl.String).replace("0", "-1")
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ -1  │
│ 2   ┆ 00  │
│ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I think this one should be an accepted answer - it will probably also work faster than `str.replace()` suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"key": ["001","0", "2"], "value": [1, 2, 0]})

result_df = df.with_columns(pl.all().str.replace(r"^0$", "-1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to define the exact string you wish to replace -
`df.with_columns(pl.all().str.replace(r"^0$", "-1"))`

Answer (score 0):

test DataFrame:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "sku1": ["1", "3", "00", "2"],
    "sku2": ["1", "00","0","-1"],
})

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ sku1 ┆ sku2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ 3    ┆ 00   │
│ 00   ┆ 0    │
│ 2    ┆ -1   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Now you can use [`when().then().otherwise()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) method to replace all `0` strings with `-1`:

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.all() != "0").then(pl.all()).fill_null("-1")
    )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ sku1 ┆ sku2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ 3    ┆ 00   │
│ 00   ┆ -1   │
│ 2    ┆ -1   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Just to explain how does it work. When you run `pl.all() != "0"` it essentially creates a mask with True / False based on the condition:

```
df.with_columns(pl.all() != "0")

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ sku1 ┆ sku2  │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ bool ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ true ┆ true  │
│ true ┆ true  │
│ true ┆ false │
│ true ┆ true  │
└──────┴───────┘
```

Now, what you want is to keep values there if mask is `true` but replace them with `-1` when it's not. If you just apply the condition you get the following result - notice `null` in place of `0`:

```
df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.all() != "0").then(pl.all()))

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ sku1 ┆ sku2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ 3    ┆ 00   │
│ 00   ┆ null │
│ 2    ┆ -1   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Now, you just use [`fill_null()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html) to change `null` to `-1`.